# Get position of data from database using x and y coordinates stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, location, coordinates

I am creating a family tree in which the user can input information about family members and drag them onto the position they want on the page.

I have a html form in which a user can input information about a specific family member and this is stored in a database. Once the user inputs a name, it is then displayed back on the web page and can be dragged around the page. This then stores the x and y coordinates of the position of which the name is dropped by the user.

My question is, I would now like to call out any previous names inserted and have them displayed on the webpage in the position in which the user left them.

I'm really struggling with this and have searched everywhere with no avail.

If anyone could give me some advice or point me in the right direction of where to find something along those lines that would be great.

I have provided the main code for inserting the x and y coordinates into the database below.

```
foreach($data->coords as $item) {
//Extract X number for panel
$coord_X = preg_replace('/[^\d\s]/', '', $item->coordTop);
//Extract Y number for panel
$coord_Y = preg_replace('/[^\d\s]/', '', $item->coordLeft);
//escape our values - as good practice
$x_coord = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $coord_X);
$y_coord = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $coord_Y);

//Setup our Query
$sql = "UPDATE members SET x_pos = '$x_coord', y_pos = '$y_coord' where member_id = $member_id";
//Execute our Query
$mysqli->query($sql) or die("Error updating Coords :".$mysqli->error);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in the position in which the user left them" ? Can you clarify a bit more? Maybe you need a SELECT query ?

Comment: I mean that when the user drags them to where they want them on their family tree, the x and y coordinates are stored within the database. So I just need the members that have previously been inputted to the database (with their x and y coordinates) to display in their location when the user logs in again. Does that make sense?

Comment: In that case you might want to store the previous information in a separate "history" table before running the update query for that particular set of coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just select the previously inserted members and display them?

```
SELECT * from members
```

Comment: When I do this, it displays the names back out onto the page but not in their x and y position?